# Multi-parameter Path in Rails and HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

So I'm using Rails and jQuery Mobile.a4 and I'm having trouble generating a path that looks like `/date/2011/04/04` while inputting that manually works fine.

#### config/routes.rb

```
root :to => 'events#date', :constraints => {:user_agent => /Mobile|webOS|BlackBerry/}
match '/date/:year/:month/:day' => 'events#date', 
    :constraints => {:user_agent => /Mobile|webOS|BlackBerry/}
```

#### app/controllers/events_controller.rb

```
def date
    unless params[:year].nil?
        @today = Date.new(params[:year].to_i, params[:month].to_i, params[:day].to_i)
    else
        @today = Date.today
    end

    respond_to :html
end
```

#### app/views/events/date.mobile.haml

```
= link_to (@today - 1.days).strftime("%A"), 
    {:action => "date", :year => @today.year, :month => @today.month, :day => (@today - 1.days).day}
```

#### path generated

```
/?day=1&month=4&year=2011
```

#### looking to generate

```
/date/2011/04/01
```

What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= link_to (@today - 1.days).strftime("%A"), "/date/#{@today.year}/#{@today.month}/#{@today.day}" %>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand...
<%= link_to "something", url, :data-role => "button" %> If this is wrong, open a new question and post here the url to it